# Merging two tables using datasets and display in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, dataset

I have these two tables

Table One
CODE    TITLE

KANT-015    How to Build a Brand

KANT-016    Avoiding the Workforce Crisis

KANT-017    Creating Winning Social Media Strategies

KANT-028    Be Prepared to Lead

KANT-029    The Values-Based Leader

Table Two

CODE

KANT-015

KANT-016

KANT-017

KANT-028

KANT-029

How can I merge them in one dataset to dosplay them in one grid view

This is what I have done so far

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\LR Product Database 2000.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        setOleDb = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter dbaOle = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblProducts", conn);

        dbaOle.Fill(setOleDb);
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LRVWebsite"].ToString());
        sqlCon.Open();
        dsSql = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName, C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
        //@"SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName,C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
        dba.Fill(dsSql);

        dsSql.Merge(setOleDb);

        GridView1.DataSource = dsSql;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        sqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: so is this merge working,what is your current problem ?

Comment: I need to have the CODE and the TITLE next to each other in the gridview. Right now it is seperate from one another

Comment: Is it for display purposes only?

Comment: use some SQL INNER JOIN with some primary key .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a PK, the merge happens on a PK.

Set one on both tables:

```
setOleDb.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = setOleDb.Tables[0].Columns["CODE"];
```